# Passing variables to YML file from PHP while parsing YML

Tags: php, laravel, variables, yaml, template-engine

Here is my YML file:

```
edit: '0'
parent: '0'
seo_title: 'gallery |'
seo_description: ''
seo_keywords: ''
fbtab: '0'
status: '1'
exceptions: {% pageType %}
calltoaction: 0
```

in PHP file:

```
$pageType = "something";
dump(Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('pathToYmlFile')));
```

Problem is passing `$pageType` to YML file

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Add a variable to a file and overwrite the original? Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have tried using %variable% and i haven't found much doc on passing the variables to  yml actually, so using Symfony yml package

Answer (score 2):

YAML is not a templating language. It has no knowledge about *variables* or *replacement*. You have two options:

- Use a templating language to preprocess your YAML file before parsing it. This is done for example in SaltStack with YAML and Jinja.
- Make the replacements inside the loaded strings *after* parsing. This makes only sense for some specific use-cases, like when some YAML value always will be replaced by a variable value, but multiple different variables can be chosen inside the YAML for replacement.

A third option would be to use YAML *tags* to denote that the value you give is a variable name. Example:

```
exceptions: !var pageType
```

`!var` here defines an explicit tag for the following scalar `pageType`. Most YAML implementations would allow you to register a custom constructor for a `!var` tagged scalar – Unfortunately, Symphony's YAML component is not equipped to do such things, so this is not an option you can go for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need this.

Remember, you convert a YAML-file into a PHP structure.

**After** you parsed it, you can do whatever you want with that structure. So, you can assign the value you want to the appropriate field.

Pseudo-code:

```
$pageType = "something";
$parsed = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('pathToYmlFile'));
$parsed->exceptions = $pageType;
```

You didn't specify your particular use-case, but, as far as I see from your code sample, it fits.